# Triming URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been reading a lot about rewriting but simply I'cant make it done the right way.

So my question is how can I with .htacces and rewrite rule make this link :

[www.website.com/?section=rijecnik](http://www.website.com/?section=rijecnik)

look like this

[www.website/rijecnik](http://www.website/rijecnik)

Now I'm using this rule but it doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ?section=$i
```

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove leading slash after `RewriteRule`.

Your code should look like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /?section=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tnx for the response but It seems like it's not working, everything stays the same as it was.

Comment: Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled and htaccess allowed in your Apache server configuration